# Put editable field in Kibana

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, efk

I'm working with EFK and I would like to know if I can put a field that can be modified by the user in a table lens (or something else as long as it is an array).
It's like a note or a comment about the line.

It is possible to put an editable field in Kibana ?

I saw old posts saying it wasn't possible, but I can't clearly find for now.

Thanks,

Aleridia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is not possible to do with Kibana.